# Route IP range outside of VPN?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

So I am somewhat more of a newb when it comes to routing IP ranges. My main problem is that I need to route a couple ranges outside of a VPN that I use.

I've run into a few issues with this.

I don't quite know how to specify a higher level range of IP address to route. I haven't been successful so far.

EX: I need to route Tivo traffic for my OTA tivo. I need to route everything that is a 1 here, how can I write that into the route command? 111.111.110.000. Range I need to route for this example is 208.73.180.0 through 208.73.183.255. I tried ip route add 208.73.18.0/24 but that didn't work.

I need to figure out how to route that whole range outside of my VPN which I assume is going to be:

```
ip route add ???.???.???.???/?? dev eth0 via 192.168.1.1
```

/w the ?'s filled in once I figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CIDR notation for the range of IP addresses 208.73.180.0 - 208.73.183.255 is `208.73.180.0/22`.

Expressing in binary:

```
208.73.180.0   -> 11010000.01001001.10110100.00000000
208.73.183.255 -> 11010000.01001001.10110111.11111111
                  ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
```

There are 22 leading bits which will be identical for all addresses in that range.

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense and yet I couldn't get to that idea. That helped me understand it better.